# How can I make sure my infant doesn't get injured on my collar bone when he suddenly jerks forward?

Tags: infant, safety, teething, moving

Lately while holding my little boy, he's been pushing his face into my chest and neck, presumably to soothe the itch of teething.

Sometimes, particularly when he's tired, he moves very fast and with a lot of force. More than once he's hit his mouth or nose off of my collar bone, and somehow, I don't think it's good and I don't want it to continue, or I'd like to lessen the rough impact on my bony collar bone.

I'm hoping for suggestions either for something practical that I can wear to make it less hard, or for ways to encourage him to change this behaviour.

How can I lessen the danger of injury to my son when he jerks forward suddenly to bury his head in my torso?

Comment: Does he cry when he hits his nose or mouth off you?

Comment: Sometimes he does. There's no way it doesn't hurt at least a little bit, because when he headbutts my nose I can promise you it doesn't tickle.

Comment: my son broke my nose doing this. But his head is a lot thicker than my nose. There's little you can do, it's unpredictable, and he'll grow out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Babies have been doing this since the beginning of time. They are flexible little beings, and any discomfort will likely be minor and short-lived. But if you are concerned, keep a burp cloth (cloth diaper or nappy) over your shoulder whenever you hold him. It protects your clothes as well!!

Comment: Thank you for a good suggestion, I'm not sure if I can do it every time but I'll try to keep something soft around whenever I can.